# Symfony/Twig: form attribute "action" is empty - why?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I build forms like it's documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html). Submitting/saving works, but the `action=""`-attribute is empty.

Here's the affected block (notice: `action="{{ action }}"`).

```
{% block form_start -%}
{% set attr = attr|merge({'class': (attr.class|default('') ~ ' myFormClass')|trim}) %}

{% set method = method|upper %}
{%- if method in ["GET", "POST"] -%}
    {% set form_method = method %}
{%- else -%}
    {% set form_method = "POST" %}
{%- endif -%}
<form name="{{ form.vars.name }}" method="{{ form_method|lower }}" action="{{ action }}"{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}{% if multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %}>
{%- if form_method != method -%}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="{{ method }}" />
{%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_start %}
```

I wonder if there's a simple parameter to set which default is *"do not fill the action-attribute"*.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you setting the action using something like `->setAction($this->generateUrl('your_route'))`?

Comment: @Qoop No, I don't. I actually expect Symfony to set the attribute by default when generating the form. Do I have to set it manually?

Comment: Yes, you have to set the action. Due to the fact that controllers can be used be used under any route it would be a lot of wasted work for Symfony to automagically guess the correct route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add action parameter while creating a form object. For example this is how function creating form in your controller could look:

```
protected function createMyForm($entity)
{
    $form = $this->createForm($this->get(newMyFormType(), $entity, array(
        'action' => $this->generateUrl('my_form_action')
        'method' => 'POST',
    ));

    return $form;
}
```